# Is there any way to draw a bitmap but only the bitmap pixels not a rectangle around it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
private Image Lighter(Image imgLight, int level, int nRed, int nGreen, int nBlue)
{
     if (changeImageColor == true)
     {
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgLight);
            int conversion = (5 * (level - 50));
            Pen pLight = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(conversion, nRed,
                                    nGreen, nBlue), imgLight.Width * 2);
            graphics.DrawLine(pLight, -1, -1, imgLight.Width, imgLight.Height);
            graphics.Save();
            graphics.Dispose();
      }
      return imgLight;
}
```

Then in the timer tick event:

```
changeImageColor = true;
img = Lighter(img, x++, colToFadeTo.R, colToFadeTo.G, colToFadeTo.B);
if (x < 55)
  {
     this.Invalidate();
  }
```

Then in paint event:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (changeImageColor == false)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
    else
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

First time im running the program i see the bmp:

[image: Bmp]

And then after its doing the Lighter method and drawing the img i see:

[image: Img]

When its drawing the img its drawing a rectangle aorund the bitmap. Is there anyway to draw/pint only on the bitmap/image it self and not around like this ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but bmp's do not support transparencies. You're going to get a rectangular image either way, it's just a matter of making the background either transparent, or the same color as the rest of the form.

Comment: winforms doesn't support transparency. You're looking for WPF.

Comment: A Bitmap Object certainly does support transparency. And so does Winforms; `Opacity` and `TransparencyKey` is there for that reason.  It does take a bit more fiddling than with WPF though.

The problem is, the bitmap *source* doesn't have a transparent background. Start with that, and it should remain transparent even after lightening the rest of the image

Comment: Looks like you are constantly drawing over the same bitmap.  Code is incomplete since your timer event is using an img variable, your paint event, a bmp variable.

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(); bmp.MakeTransparent() or bmp.MakeTransparent(Color)

Comment: Indeed, __more (complete) code__ is needed. I see the bitmap and I see `DrawLine` and `Graphics.Save` but I see no connection